# MVC 4 - Regular Expression Validation - Why is this not working?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, regex

I have a field on an MVC 4 View which requires regular expression validation. I'm trying to limit entry to characters 'A' through 'Z' (case insensitive) only.

My C# property looks as follows:

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Revision property
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("(/^[a-z]+$/i)", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a character between 'A' and 'Z'")]
    public string Revision { get; set; }
```

The generated HTML looks as follows:

```
    <div class="formEditControl">
        <input Style="width:30px;" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please enter a character between &#39;A&#39; and &#39;Z&#39;" data-val-regex-pattern="(/^[a-z]+$/i)" data-val-required="The Revision field is required." id="Revision" name="Revision" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Revision" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
```

But when I execute it, I get the following error on valid data entry:

[image]

I don't have a great deal of experience with MVC 4 or RegEx, so it's not clear to me why this isn't working.

Comment: wouldn't a drop down be easier? is there an additional space after the  string?

Comment: and `{1}` would be better than `+`.

Comment: Are the wrapping parenthesis around the regex necessary? It could just be the regex isn't valid at all.

Comment: @Loamhoof - I thought of that, and removed them, but the problem remains.

Comment: Use just `^[a-zA-Z]$`, it should be enough if you only want one character.

Comment: .NET does not use pattern delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `(/` to start with, but this makes the delimiters `()`.  I'm not sure that you even need delimiters at all.  Remove the `(` and `)`.  If that doesn't work, use

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: I've already tried removing the '(' and ')'. It doesn't make any difference. However, your reg ex expression did the trick. Not sure why. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't make `(` and `)` delimiters because .NET does not use pattern delimiters. The original pattern doesn't work because it's trying to find literal `/` in the target text.

Answer (score 1):

You're regular expression is only allowing lowercase characters. Therefore when you input a 'D' it responded with the error. For all letters, case insensitive, your regex should look like this `^[a-zA-Z]*$`. Try that and it should work.

Comment: The i modifier should allow case insensitive entry. Entering a lower case 'd' generates the same error. I think there is something fundamentally wrong with the way the regular expression is being evaluated.

Comment: @RandyMinder Use `(?i)` at the beginning of your pattern to turn on case-insensitivity.

Comment: (?i) will not work if client-side validation is enabled because JavaScript's Regex class doesn't support the same features as .NET's Regex class. The only solution that will work on both client and server is manually specifying [A-Za-z] for each character.